# Manipulating variables in external functions and returning them (JS)

Tags: javascript, function, scope

Simple example:

```
function getSongs() {
  let title = '';
  let name = '';

  getTitle(title);
  getName(name);

  console.log(title, name)
}

function getTitle(title) {
  title = 'Welcome Back';
  return title;
}

function getName(name) {
  name = 'The Black Crusaders'
  return name;
}

getSongs();
```

I'm trying to do this with several external API's (getting data from the API's in external functions and using that data in the original function), but for the sake of simplicity, above example will do.

Preferably, it would be even better if I didn't have to initialize the variables (title, name) in the first function, but I guess I have to do to this, due to function scope?

I don't know how to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You *can't* do it. What you can do is `title = getTitle(title);` and thusly assign the returned value to the variable in the calling context

Comment: or you can pass the data as `object` or `array` (where the modification in the function has effect on the instance). If the external API or implementation allows it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something more simple:

```
function getSongs() {
  var title = getTitle();
  var name = getName();
  console.log(title, name)
}

function getTitle() {
  return 'Welcome Back';
}

function getName() {
  return 'The Black Crusaders'
}

getSongs();
```